# OSX Lion MySql - MIA?

Tags: mysql, macos

I hear that OSX LIon does not have MySql packaged...is it true? Ok, no biggie but my question is: what happens if you upgrade from Snow Leopard?

Does it bork all your existing dbs? Is it utter mayhem? Or easy (please say yes!).

Comment: Perhaps better directed at Serverfault?

Comment: AFAIK, Apple has never shipped MySQL with any version of OS X (at least non-server ones).  Why should Lion be any different?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that Lion comes with a stock MySQL installation, however if you're upgrading from Snow Leopard, Lion should not touch your current MySQL configurations.

However, as always, backing up first is heavily advised.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Lion from Snow Leopard and my MySQL installation seemed to survive just fine. I can merrily browse through my databases with Navicat as before. However, my php/MySQL projects (Drupal, Moodle) and all my Ruby on Rails apps ceased to work. (Haven't investigated enough to comment further on that yet.)

Caution advised, depending on your situation.